# Why do you redeclare PropertyChangedEventHandler isn't it redunded?

Tags: c#, data-binding

The boiler plate OnPropertyChanged code that you will likely see in almost any databinding example is as follows

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{    
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler!=null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Isn't this redundant though? Wouldn't it be easier to say this

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {    
         if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I am sure there is a reason why we do this I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the second implementation it's possible for another thread to remove the only remaining event handler after the null check passes but before the delegate is invoked, resulting in a null referee exception.  By copying the delegate before the check (delegates are immutable, removing a handler means assigning a new delegate, not mutating the existing one) means that such a NRE isn't possible.  What is possible however is to invoke a handler *after* is has been removed, which can also cause problems.

If you know that the event will not have handlers added/removed from a thread other than the thread firing the event, then the two are equivalent.

Comment: but in either case you are invoking the original property changed event. So if it were deregistered it would still cause a null reference exception

Comment: @AMR No it would not.  As I say, delegates are immutable.  Removing a handler is not mutating the object referenced, rather it is creating a new delegate and assigning that to `PropertyChanged`.  When you pull it out to a local it will either be null, or not.  It will never change, even if the field that was used to set it is changed.